# WMIC + Python Subprocess/ (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, wmic

I'm trying to kill an .exe with subprocess.Popen.

Solution as:

1. `taskkill /im (.exe) /t /f`
2. `taskkill /pid (.exe) /t /f`

aren't working as the response is access denied. Indeed, as i'm running the cmd from subprocess i'm not able to obtain admin privilegies.

I've found a command to kill this process from cmd (without running it as admin) which is:

3. `wmic process where name=".exe" delete`

... but when i'm running it with subprocess it gives me "`invalid query`".
The command i'm running is:

4)`subprocess.Popen(['wmic', 'process', 'where', 'name="-------.exe"', 'delete'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

I suppose that i'm writing it wrongly. Some advices?

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the filename, since you are specifying separate arguments here anyway. Does that work?

Comment: 5) subprocess.Popen(['wmic', 'process', 'where', 'name=openvpn.exe', 'delete'], shell=True) ... always invalid query :(

Comment: Sounds like some weird escaping incompatibility... A shot in the dark and probably not the best solution: `['cmd', '/c', 'wmic process where name="openvpn.exe" delete']` or maybe just pass the whole thing as string: `subprocess.popen('wmic process where name="openvpn.exe" delete')`

Comment: I've just found the solution in a reddit answer :). Thank you Cherry for you time :)

Comment: Next thing I would do is use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what command line is _actually_ passed to wmic (set filter to "operation" "begins with" "process") and compare it to how it looks when you do it from cmd where it works. That may give a clue about what's wrong.

Comment: Oh, cool. In that case, it would be nice if you would write an answer to your own question, so that future readers can find the solution too! You can later also self-accept the answer.

Comment: You should not mix a list of arguments with `shell=True`; it sometimes happens to work in weird ways, but is basically always an error. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put spaces around the comparison operator and send the whole condition (`name = xxx` or `name like xxx`) as single argument, since wmic doesn't like it to be split in parts, and internally the quotes get messed up if they are in the "middle" of a word:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['wmic', 'process', 'where', 'name like "----.exe"', 'delete'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Actually both shell=False and shell=True works. I'm a newbie and do not know the complications that could arise from shell=True. Any explanation? For example, when I lauch the .exe with the proper commands with subprocess it needs shell=True otherwise an error occurs. Instead, when using wmic if shell =False the error does not appear.

Comment: My other comment has a link to more information. Basically, this currently happens to work on Windows, but that doesn't mean it's correct; once you read the linked page, it should be obvious why not.

Comment: It's "wmic.exe", not a `wmic` shell command, and you're not using any shell command-line features such as environment-variable expansion or standard I/O redirection and piping, so using `shell=True` here is pointless.

Comment: This command is Windows only, so there's also no point in worrying about whether wmic.exe is compatible with the assumptions in `subprocess.list2cmdline`. In fact, wmic.exe calls `GetCommandLineW` and manually parses its command line instead of using C `argv` or `CommandLineToArgvW`, so it is not a normal case that's predictably compatible with passing the arguments as a list. Just use a command line string, e.g.  `subprocess.call('wmic.exe process where "name like "----.exe"" delete')`.

Comment: More simply, terminate a process by PID via `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)`. In Windows this is implemented via `TerminateProcess(hProcess, SIGTERM)`, which sets the exit status to `SIGTERM` (15). That's not a meaningful exit status in Windows, but fine. Normally in Windows the exit status of a terminated process is set to 1, but `os.kill` is written appallingly bad and conflates this with trying to send `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` (1) to a console group, with the given ID ineterpreted as a console process group ID. Only do this if it's actually a console process group that you're sending Ctrl+Break.